# Autocad Electrical 2022 flags a file as modified even if I just scroll around in it, is there a way to disable that?

Tags: electrical-engineering, cad, autocad

I'm new to using autocad, so I'll open up a document, look at it and close it without changing anything, but if I scrolled around it flags the files as modified and asks if I want to save them. It's especially annoying on a close all for a bunch of tabs. I imagine that it wants to save viewport position or somesuch.

Is there a way to disable that? I'd like to scroll, zoom, move and just close the file without it asking me to save. I only want to be asked to save if I've modified the drawing somehow.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Have you checked the helpfile?

Comment: I did not see it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way to disable that.
It has annoyed me for years.

The suggestion that there should be an "off" button for this "feature" provoked religious ire in a "Stop Save Prompt" thread on a forum hosted by AutoCAD.

A post from one of the AutoCAD faithful: "This is AutoCAD. It's always been this way and many before you have made the suggestion in forums designated for feature requests."

It seems to have been inspired by posts that agreed with a heretic who dared to say: "I'm amazed at how completely one-sided, and single minded these answers are."

The first response in the thread was: "Use the free viewer from Autodesk if all you are doing is viewing and plotting"

Another zealot piled on with, "What's confusing is using the wrong tool to view files."

It seems it is anathema to many software developers to include "off" buttons for "features" they think everyone should love as much as they do.
Never mind "personal" computing, this is the age of enforced conformity. 
Once upon a time, 16 million colors were available to customize the appearances of dialog boxes in Windows. Not now.

AutoCAD is the 800-pound gorilla. They don't need to adapt to users who expect 21st century behavior.

Comment: Bob, thanks, that is pretty annoying. have they considered id I want to compare something from another project and possibly copy/paste into mine? I doubt a viewer covers that use case.